# How to pull an element from a sublist?

Tags: scala, list

I have made a list to store some sequences of data, where each sequence contains three elements. How can I extract one of the elements from the sequence?

I have tried parentheses, like alco(0)(1) and get() and they do not work.

```
val alco = List(("Light Beer", "4%", "23 OZ"), ("Regular Beer", "6%", "23 OZ"))

val temp = alco(0).get(1)

println(temp)
```

The result shows:

> error: value get is not a member of (String, String, String)
>         val temp = alco(0).get(1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scala> val alco = List(("Light Beer", "4%", "23 OZ"), ("Regular Beer", "6%", "23 OZ"))
alco: List[(String, String, String)] = List((Light Beer,4%,23 OZ), (Regular Beer,6%,23 OZ))

scala> val (_, temp, _) = alco(0)
temp: String = 4%

scala> val temp = alco(0)._2
temp: String = 4%
```

Beware that accessing to the Scala list by index has `O(n)` complexity where `n` is size of the list. So if you want to iterate over them - prefer to use `map`, `collect`, `foldLeft` or `foreach` calls:

```
scala> alco.map { case (_, temp, _) => temp }
res0: List[String] = List(4%, 6%)

scala> alco.foreach { x => println(x._2) }
4%
6%
```

Comment: Might be worth explaining why... I guess it's a *list of tuple* not a *list of list*?

Answer (score 1):

As @Andriy pointed out:

```
val alco = List(("Light Beer", "4%", "23 OZ"), ("Regular Beer", "6%", "23 OZ"))
```

is of type `List[Tuple3[String, String, String]]` and since `Tuple3` does not have a `get` method you're receiving the error.

[scala.Tuple3](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/Tuple3.html)

To solve the problem just define your list as follows:

```
val alco = List(List("Light Beer", "4%", "23 OZ"), List("Regular Beer", "6%", "23 OZ"))
```

This way it will be of type `List[List[String]]` and your code should work.